# Kali Stuck at Log in Screen After I Installed Veil-Evasion

Tags: kali-linux

I installed veil-evasion recently and after I reboot kali, it stuck at log-in screen. I'm entering my credentials but after that a black screen appears for a short time and it takes me back to the log-in screen. I re-installed kali for several times. but whenever i install veil, rigth after this problem occured. Here's what i tried to solve this:

With pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> I log into the shell. And then:

1. I reinstalled and configured gdm3
2. I installed and configured lightdm instead of gdm3
3. I installed xorg, type startx and then reboot it.
4. I couldn't look xsessions-errors cause it doesn't exist in my system. Instead of that, I did this:

`cd /usr/share/xsessions` and here's what ı've got:

gnome-classic.desktop gnome.desktop (but i have no permission to access them)

5. I typed "chown username:username .Xauthority" but it there was no response
6. One of the suggestions was typing them:

   ```
   sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
   ```

sudo service lightdm restart But "Xauthority" wasn't a file or directory

7. I typed `apt-get install x-window-system` and after that `startx`

They were solutions that i find in several forums so I just did what they wrote. None of them worked obviously. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
2. `apt-get update`
3. `apt-get upgrade`